# Power flow direction of wind farm

Tags: power-supply

If a wind farm is connected to grid so as to transfer any excess power, how to make sure if power flows from turbine to grid and not from grid to turbine? One possibility is turbine could act as a fan by absorbing power from grid.

Comment: Who needs wind farms? It's windy enough already!

Comment: @Transistor, lol ... but is the wind organic?

Comment: the genarator cannot be connected directly to the grid because the generator output would have to be synchronized with the grid by controlling the generator speed ... it is much easier to use the generator to power an inverter ... the inverter matches its output with the power grid electronically

Comment: The same way they do this with every other generator, they create a higher voltage and current/phase at that time to ensure current flows away from the plant.

Comment: @jsotola - it must be an evil GMO. How else would they be able to grow so big?

Comment: @jsotola Practically yes, but asynchronous windmills do exist, or at least did.

Comment: @Transistor: ROFL... Nice one...

Comment: @jsotola it gets more electromagnetic than that.  I'm sure it's just one scheme of many, but the block diagram that sticks in my head is a generator with a 3-phase rotor with slip rings, and a 3-phase armature.  I can't remember which one is actually generating power, but the control system monitors the rotor position and speed, then rotates the field as necessary so that the output power is synchronized to the grid.  So there is an inverter involved, but it only has to supply field excitation -- it doesn't have to handle the full power of the generator.

Comment: If you did some research, you would find a wind machine that did use its generator as a motor to spin the blades up under certain conditions...

Comment: Use the same trick on an escalator AC drive motor.  Then you can steal energy from everyone who is using the down-escalator.   Also: use the down-escalator to power the elevator.

Answer (score 1):

The basic block diagram of a wind turbine is:

turbine --> electromechanical stuff --> complicated electronics --> the grid

Those complicated electronics pretty much insure that the turbine isn't going to be spun by the grid unless someone *wants* the turbine to be spun by the grid.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what sort of electronics is needed so that I can find relevant literature on them and understand the process better?

Comment: Not without validating the folks who want to close this question as too broad.  Try searching on "electronics for wind power generation" or similar terms, and see where you get.

Comment: And consider that you could build a purely electromechanical gizmo that could detect when the power was flowing into the turbine instead of out of it, and which could then actuate a contactor to disconnect it.  1940's technology, with no semiconductor or even vacuum tube in sight.